# Where in my code should I put my Meteor user methods and allow() permissions?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, alanning-roles

I am using alanning:roles and have put my users in admin groups successfully in my server - main file.  However now I'm trying to add Meteor.users.allow() to my admin in order to allow them to delete other users.  I'm having trouble finding an example of the right location within my code to put this.  Do I put it in the server main under startup? or in a separate users collection (I'm using React)?

I think this is illustrating a blindspot in my understanding of meteor or react so if you're feeling instructive, please help me out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Meteor more recent than 1.3.0, you can place your hooks/allows/methods files anywhere under a `server` subdirectory, as long as you `import` (as in the ES6 module import) them. It's helpful to have them separated logically.
Here is a sample directory structure we're using in our project:

```
public/ (static files, assets)
settings/ (to be loaded as command-line args for different environments)
test/
imports/
  client/
    startup/
    components/
    views/
  server/
    startup/
    allows/
    hooks/
    methods/
    publications/
  both/
    utils/
    collections/ (collections are here, because they're shared)
```

Now, to be honest, this is an older project, so React was not considered here, but this could still be helpful for you when you're organizing your imports. Obviously, you're going to need a couple of entry files for your client and server that import all of the necessary dependencies.
From then on, for example, in your `imports/server/allows/<collection_name>.js` file, you place your allows like:

```
import { SomeCollection } from '/imports/both/collections/someCollection.js';

SomeCollection.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  update: function () {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function () {
    return true;
  }
});
```

I prefer using absolute file path imports in Meteor projects, since there the root path resolves to the root of your project. Makes them easier to copy-paste.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.  I guess I'm a little unclear on if I can use the Meteor.users collection just like any collection (SomeCollection in your example).  If I name a collection users does it automatically reference Meteor.users so that I could do users.allow({remove...})?

Comment: I'm almost sure you can use Meteor.users.allow({etc...}). You should be able to name a collection 'users' as well. Please mark the answer as answered if your initial problem has been resolved.